# How to remove all items of an array except first/last n elements in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, slice

I had this question and saw that on stack overflow there isn't any information. So wanted to ask and answer in case anyone else has the same question. I found the answer from this medium post https://medium.com/@marcosantadev/arrayslice-in-swift-4e18522ab4e4#convert_slice_array

Answer (score 1):

basically `array.dropFirst(n)` lets you create an ArraySlice with all elements but the first n elements. But in Swift we cannot assign an ArraySlice to be an array. Therefore, we need to use Array() to convert it into an array and reassign it to the original array

```
nodes = Array(nodes.dropFirst(n))
```

This line allows you to get an array that doesn't have the first n elements of iteself